# What is the difference between "git push remote branch" and "git push remote HEAD:branch"?

Tags: git

Trying the former, I got `error: src refspec branch does not match any.`, whilst trying the latter succeeded.

In case it's noteworthy, the branch name was `1.3`.

What's the difference between these two, and why did the first fail when the second succeeded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That when you say `HEAD:branch` you *don't* need to have a local branch with the same name of the remote branch on your local... when you type `git push some-remote HEAD:some-branch` you are asking it to put whatever you have checked out at the moment as the remote branch, regardless of what it is called on your local (or working on *detached HEAD*).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error you saw, your local repository does not seem to have a branch named `branch`, but the remote repository must have had one already, for example if a collaborator already pushed to `branch`.

The particular argument to [`git push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) in question is known as the [refspec](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push-ltrefspecgt82308203), and with a colon separator, you can in effect rename branches or objects on the remote  side. Therefore, a refspec of `HEAD:branch` means push the branch beginning at the most recent commit on the current branch if the `HEAD` [symbolic reference](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-symbolic-ref) refers to a branch (or the commit that `HEAD` refers to if [detached](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#_detached_head)) but to the ref `branch` on the remote side.

For completeness, if `branch` does not yet exist on the remote, you must invoke

```
git push remote HEAD:refs/heads/branch
```

> **`<refspec>`**…​
>
> Specify what destination ref to update with what source object. The
>   format of a `<refspec>` parameter is an optional plus `+`, followed by the
>   source object `<src>`, followed by a colon `:`, followed by the
>   destination ref `<dst>`.
>
> The  is often the name of the branch you would want to push, but
>   it can be any arbitrary "SHA-1 expression", such as `master~4` or `HEAD`
>   (see [gitrevisions](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions)).
>
> The  tells which ref on the remote side is updated with this
>   push. Arbitrary expressions cannot be used here, an actual ref must be
>   named. If `git push [<repository>]` without any `<refspec>` argument is
>   set to update some ref at the destination with `<src>` with
>   `remote.<repository>.push` configuration variable, `:<dst>` part can be
>   omitted—​such a push will update a ref that `<src>` normally updates
>   without any `<refspec>` on the command line. Otherwise, missing `:<dst>`
>   means to update the same ref as the `<src>`.